# How to Launch a Program and Two Returns

Tags: windows-7, automation, launcher, carriage-return

I want to launch a program that then produces two dialog boxes I wish to just hit ENTER for. How do I do this? I have this so far but want it followed with RETURN twice.

> w:: Run E:\Program Files\Windows Media 7 PowerToys\Player\clearmru.exe

Comment: Does typing "clearmru.exe /?" at the command prompt produce any help?

Answer (score 1):

The ClearMRU program in the Windows Media 7 Power Toys has a command line option to run it without any prompts.

```
clearmru.exe /q
```

In your case add /q to the end of the command line.

You can also create a shortcut to the program on your start menu with the same command line so you can run it without starting a command prompt.